# How to specify languages Google Play should recognize?

Tags: java, android, google-play

I have default language english in my app and german as the only translation. For recognition in GooglePlay I wrote `resConfigs "en", "de"` into my gradle file.
Now GooglePlay tells me something like `I found standard and german` but I can write my changelog only in german (which seems to be the default by the way?) - Can anyone help me how to define the languages so that GooglePlay recognizes english as default and german as additional translation?

Answer (score 0):

Specify languages in value folder like for german make value folder "values-de" and create your string file there and for default value use folder "vaule" .Google will recognize all language according to country itself

Comment: Yes I already did that but I cant translate my changelog in GooglePlay dev console into different languages - is this normal?